# PowerBI - Equally split value over months between Start and End dates

Tags: powerbi

I've recently been trying to learn various pieces of PowerBI and have hit some strange brick wall. I'd normally resolve this further upstream in the database, but it's not possible at this time.

I have a single table. I also have a date table, although my hope is to join that onto the result table below to measure monthly targets.

[image: Finance Table]

I have a need to equally split the Value column into every month (incomplete or not) between the start and end dates. e.g. If the Start Date is 01/01/2023 and end date is 22/04/2023 - It will span 4 months (Jan, Feb, March, April). Equally splitting the value 4 times.

Something like this:

[image: Example Result]

How would I do this? (Any other, better ideas welcome)
Also what is this sort of process called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PowerQuery, add a Custom Column with:

```
let 
  sd = [Start Date], ed = [End Date], v = [Value],
  lstDates = List.Generate(
    () => [x=Date.StartOfMonth(sd)],
    each [x] <= Date.StartOfMonth(ed),
    each [x = Date.AddMonths([x], 1)],
    each [x]
  ),
  lstValue = List.Repeat({v/List.Count(lstDates)}, List.Count(lstDates)),
  result = Table.FromColumns({ lstDates, lstValue }, {"Date", "Value"})
in
  result
```

- Then once added, remove columns Start Date, End Date, and Value.
- Then expand the new column without `Use original column name as prefix`

[image]

Full code:

```
let
    Source = YOURSOURCE,
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"Start Date", type date}, {"End Date", type date}, {"Value", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each 
let 
  sd = [Start Date], ed = [End Date], v = [Value],
  lstDates = List.Generate(
    () => [x=Date.StartOfMonth(sd)],
    each [x] <= Date.StartOfMonth(ed),
    each [x = Date.AddMonths([x], 1)],
    each [x]
  ),
  lstValue = List.Repeat({v/List.Count(lstDates)}, List.Count(lstDates)),
  result = Table.FromColumns({ lstDates, lstValue }, {"Date", "Value"})
in result),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom",{"ID", "Custom"}),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Custom", {"Date", "Value"}, {"Date", "Value"})
in
    #"Expanded Custom"
```

Comment: Thanks! This is horrendously clever and I don't understand it. Is there any background reading or popular search terms I can use to learn about this stuff?